# About creating own attributes for pre-existing Widgets like Edittext, TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, attributes

Help! I want to know whether we can create own custom Attributes for pre-existing android components like EditText, TextView, AutoCompleteTextView, MultiAutoCompleteTextView etc.

Using XML I need to implement a custom attribute/property to an autocompletetextview so that it do not show autocomplete suggestions if property is set false, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. There is this thing that is called binding adapters, and you could use those as new xml attributes. Well, ofcourse, you have to enable data binding on your project to make the binding adapters to work.

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

**Bonus:** If you are using kotlin, you could instead make these binding adapters into extension functions such that you could use them as an extension function for your objects.

**Update**

To xml attributes for pre-existing widgets, you first need to define a custom binding adapter. Here is an example of a custom binding adapter:

```java
// This will change the text views background color and text when it is tapped
@BindingAdapter("changeBackgroundAndTextOnTap")
public static void changeBackgroundAndTextOnTap(final TextView view, boolean shouldChange) {
    // The first parameter is the type of view this xml attribute will be available to
    // The second is the value you will receive from the xml attribute
    if (shouldChange) {
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{(int)Math.round(Math.random() * 360), 0.8f, 0.4f}));
                view.setText("" + (Math.random() * 10000000000L));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But before we could use this, we should first tell android that we are using data binding, so in your app level build.gradle file, add this line:

```
android {
...
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
...
}
```

Next, to make data binding work on your xml files, you first have to wrap your layouts inside  tags, like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Don't Click Me!"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:textColor="#dedede"
        android:background="#000000"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</layout>
```

Then, on your activity, or fragment, you should set content view using databinding util:

```java
private ActivityMainBinding mBinding; //Optional

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Now that you are all set, you could now use your custom xml attribute a.k.a. data binding adapter on your layouts like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Don't Click Me!"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:textColor="#dedede"
        android:background="#000000"
        changeBackgroundAndTextOnTap="@{true}" // Note: the @{} is necessary
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</layout>
```

For an example project, here is a github repo:
https://github.com/jianastrero/Android-Data-Binding-Example-In-Java

Comment: Hey Jian, thanks for this article link but please can you write and provide an example code for the following as i find documentation typical and unclear.

Comment: Could i get back to you on 17:00 UTC+8? I'm currently at work now. Do you use java or kotlin?

Comment: I use Java & yes please do help whenever you are free.

Comment: Hey man, sorry for the delay. I have just updated my answer with an example.

Comment: A million thanks and shoutout to you my man, you are a real savior. gratitude and respect.

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: Do you Blog on Medium.com?

Comment: I have planned on, but i'm busy on work so i'd rather just answer questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Man,but the link you provided to your github project do not have any databinding stuff. It just show a simple default created class. But the above code does help.

Comment: Also, can you please give score to my question, it really helps.

Comment: Sure thing. I just updated the github repo. i forgot to push my local repo. my bad.

Comment: Help!!, can't we do what you did in CustomAdapter Class in MainActivity itself, cause my code ain't yet working. as getresources() cannot be called from a static method and method used for databinding needs to be static, also while i make ArrayAdapter in the CustomAdapter class, we need to pass this as a refrence which is not poosible in CustomAdapter as we are not extending any kinda activity in the CustomAdapter Class.

Comment: You could use View.getResources() - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getResources()
to a reference of resources. If you need a context, use View.getContext() - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getContext()
to get the context.

The first parameter of every CustomAdapter is a view, so, I guess you get it now.

Comment: It worked!, sorry for bothering you again, also thanks again.

Comment: No prob. I'm glad to help.